# SQL Server - Identity column Guid

Tags: sql-server-2012

**EDIT** :
Well looks like the only permanent part is the last part, everytime a new session is opened the other parts also change.

**Is there any way to control this** ?

**------------------------------------------------**

I created an identity primary key column on SQL Server 2012.

I noticed that everytime a new record is created the only part that changes is the first part.  The other parts marked as **XXX** below remain the same. Will it change in the future? Maybe after some millions of records?

**(e.g 85BD420D-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)**

The table was created using MVC Code First, however please find below the script generation

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Transactions]    Script Date: 17-01-2014 11:25:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [TransactionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TransactionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste the CREATE TABLE script please?

Comment: It looks like NEWSEQUENTIALID() could be in use here, but its hard for me to know if SQL Server is generating the GUID or if .net code is doing it. Once you know which is doing it and what method they are using, you should be able to get to the documentation of the method\function - example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx